# Cant deploy app to Heroku node modules too big

Tags: heroku

My node modules by itself take up 500MB.
Heroku only allows 500MB. My complete app is about 700MB. What do web developers do to deploy their app and bypass this problem? It seems create-react-app downloads so much node modules to where it is almost impossible to deploy the app.

Comment: 500mb is the *slug* size limit, at the end of the build. CRA dependencies are largely for dev, what you're deploying in the slug should just be the outputs: HTML, CSS, bundled JS and any assets. You can do this by e.g. chaining the node and staticfile buildpacks, as I do here: https://github.com/textbook/react-ts-fe/blob/main/bin/prepare-heroku.sh

Comment: Have you _tried_ deploying it?

Comment: Okay I will try to use the Buildpack thing. thank you ....what about .slugignore do I need to use it?

Comment: I have tried to deploy it everything is good except the slug size thank you for your input

Comment: hey jonrshape I tied to deploy and I get this` App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static` do I have to add some kind of file to my code?

Comment: Per https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static#deploying you need a static.json to use that buildpack, in the same way that the node one looks for package.json.

Comment: thank you I will use this ....found out my my public folder is 300MB ...this is embarrassing so many images and music ha

Answer (score -2):

Try adding /node_modules to your .gitignore.

Comment: Although this is good practice in general, Heroku will `npm install` the dependencies so it doesn't solve the slug size problem (and may be what the OP already has - CRA sets this by default.